# Usw add_rewrite_rule to display frontpage on specific page

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to do a very simple rewrite rule, but can't get it to work.

I want to have my frontpage displayed, when a specific URL is typed in, like so: `www.mydomain.com/mypage` should display `www.mydomain.com` (my frontpage)

I tried some things, that all didn't work:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^mypage', '/', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^mypage', 'index.php?slide=$matches[1]', 'top')
add_rewrite_rule('^mypage', 'index.php?post=1', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^mypage', 'index.php?page_id=1', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^mypage', 'index.php', 'top');
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I just tried the following locally: `add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/?','index.php','top');` + refreshing permalinks. Worked, so I can't really reproduce your problem .. Are you sure no other plugin/theme is the problem?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that one has to refresh the permalinks in order for it to work. Thank you!

Comment: To be brutally honest, in my local version I didn't have to. But it is suggested ([as in this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-2038)). So it works now?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. Although I thought this would make it possible to not have the URL changed and just have a different page displayed. But I guess add_rewrite_rule isn't exactly meant to work that way...